# From logistic regression coefficients to marginal distributions of the dependent variable

Tags: logistic

I have the coefficients for a logistic regression model with $25$ independent variables of mixed continuous and categorical types.

Considering one particular categorical independent variable with $2$ levels so that in the linear model we have a term $x_{i1}$ taking a value of either $0$ or $1$ and an associated coefficient $\beta_1$, is it possible to infer from the value of $\beta_1$ what proportion of $y_i$ in the data used to train the model had a value of $1$?

Comment: You mean, knowing _only_ $\beta_1$ and not the other coefficients related to the other regressors?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I have values for all of the other coefficients. What I don't have is access to the data used to train the model in the first place.

Comment: So you know the $\hat \beta$s but you don't know the $X's$... do you know $\mathbf x_i'\hat \beta$ (as a sum per observation)? Do you know the sample size?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Correct, I don't know $X$, nor do I know the fitted values. I have a value for the sample size but don't know if it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the usual logistic regression model (that includes a constant)

$$P(y_i \mid 1, \mathbf x_i') = \Lambda (\alpha+\mathbf x_i'\beta) = \left(1+\exp\{-\mathbf \alpha-\mathbf x_i'\beta\}\right)^{-1}\qquad i=1,...,n$$

the maximum likelihood estimator is such that, among other relations, we have

$$\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^ny_i = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n\Lambda (\hat \alpha_{MLE}+\mathbf x_i'\hat \beta_{MLE})$$

The LHS is the proportion of the $y_i$'s taking the value $1$ in the sample. So in order to recover this proportion one would need to know the RHS -either component per component (the sample size and the estimated probabilities per observation), or as a single number (the "average probability").

So one does not need to know the regressor matrix, but, one needs to know something more than the values of the estimated coefficients, since moreover, there is no closed-form expression for the estimator.